# Why is my regex with split() leaving spaces after single punctuation?

Tags: java, regex, split

There are an abundance of questions on here about String.split() and regex, but none of them seem to pertain to my dilemma here ...

I have the following:

```
string a = "@USER_78b1ff36 just a hunch............     You 
two seem to know your baseball, and may have been teammates before....";

splitTweet = tweets[i].split("\\.+|\\s+|\\*+|\\,+|\\!+|\"|\\-|/|\\:");
printArray(splitTweet); //prints line by line the index followed by value
```

OUTPUT:

```
0: @USER_78b1ff36
1: just
2: a
3: hunch
4: 
5: You
6: two
7: seem
8: to
9: know
10: your
11: baseball
12: 
13: and
14: may
15: have
16: been
17: teammates
18: before
```

I'm getting these spaces, but they only occur for single instances of punctuation, white space is broken as expected, and multiple instances of punctuation are broken as expected ...

What am I doing wrong with my expression?(I'm sure there are multiple things, this is the first time I've tried using split() ) I want to have only words, but I do need to include @ and # if they're attached to a token.

Comment: Did you try `\\s+` instead of `\\s`?

Comment: Sorry, I had that in must have copied an older version of the expression, just a sec.

Comment: @devnull, There, that's what I have currently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
"baseball, and"
```

splits into

```
"baseball"
""
"and"
```

because `", "` is two delimiters. Your `+` quantifiers only allow runs of a single kind of delimiter. If you want to split on runs of different delimiters, put `+` around the whole thing rather than the parts:

```
a.split("(\\.|\\s|\\*|\\,|\\!|\"|\\-|/|\\:)+");
```